# How to get the index of currently displayed child from RemoteViews if I am using ViewFlipper in AppWidget?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-remoteview

I am writing an app widget and have used `ViewFlipper` in it. Have a look at following image. I have attached `PendingIntent` to the left arrow button (top left corner) to navigate through `ViewFlipper`'s childs (the white area).

There are 3 childs `Today`, `Tomorrow` and `SomeDay`. Implementation of `ViewFlipper` works fine, but I am not able to change the title as per the currently displayed child. There is an API `getDisplayedChild()` in `ViewFlipper` which returns the index of currently displayed child. But that isn't available in `RemoteViews`.

Is there any API in `RemoteViews` or any work around to fulfill this requirement?

[image]

Comment: Faced the same issue. Don't have too much time for this, but I'll dig deeper on this eventually and let you know what I came up to. Please do the same if you find something